# Get all date using Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using rest assured to test my API, I have an array list which contains date which I need to compare with JSON response, but I am not able to get all date values from the response

```
ArrayList<String> jsonElement = response.path("result[0].data[0].record.date");
```

I am getting records for the first array object only

Below is my JSON response

```
{
      "statusCode": 200,
      "result": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "record": [
                {
                  "date": "2016-09-07T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2016-07-07T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2016-07-21T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2017-03-31T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2017-01-30T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "record": [
                {
                  "date": "2017-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2017-08-07T00:00:00.000000Z"
                },
                {
                  "date": "2018-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "id": "34567890"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?.

Comment: I am get record for first node only

Comment: @Cod - Did you try it out ?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of different ways to get this done, but considering result will always be 1 here's a solution

```
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(json);

    ArrayList<String> original = new ArrayList<String>();

    int count = js.getInt("result[0].data.size()");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        original.addAll(js.get("result[0].data[" + i + "].record.date"));
    }

    System.out.println("Dates : "+original);
    System.out.println("Count : "+original.size());
    System.out.println("Third Date : "+original.get(2));
```

**Output :**

```
Dates : [2016-09-07T00:00:00.000000Z, 2016-07-07T00:00:00.000000Z, 2016-07-21T00:00:00.000000Z, 2017-03-31T00:00:00.000000Z, 2017-01-30T00:00:00.000000Z, 2017-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z, 2017-08-07T00:00:00.000000Z, 2018-01-06T00:00:00.000000Z]
Count : 8
Third Date : 2016-07-21T00:00:00.000000Z
```